# Trying to update composer packages with PHP 8

Tags: php, composer-php

On my dev machine I have PHP 8, I'm trying to get Composer to upgrade some packages but it keeps giving errors about the PHP version despite all the packages having updates that support PHP 8.

I've no idea how to get around this issue?

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires abraham/twitteroauth ^1.2 -> satisfiable by abraham/twitteroauth[1.2.0].
    - abraham/twitteroauth 1.2.0 requires php ^7.2 || ^7.3 || ^7.4 -> your php version (8.0.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.0.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - google/apiclient v2.7.2 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~5.3.1||~6.0||~7.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.0.1].
    - google/apiclient is locked to version v2.7.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

Tried **forcing** a newer version that I want and still doesn't work:

```
composer update abraham/twitteroauth:3.0.0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires abraham/twitteroauth ^1.2, 3.0.0, found abraham/twitteroauth[dev-dependabot/npm_and_yarn/concurrently-6.2.1, dev-dependabot/npm_and_yarn/path-parse-1.0.7, dev-dependabot/npm_and_yarn/prettier/plugin-php-0.17.3, dev-dependabot/composer/phpmd/phpmd-2.10.2, dev-dependabot/composer/phpunit/phpunit-9.5.8, dev-main, dev-master, dev-subdomains, 0.2.1, ..., 0.9.2, 1.0.0, ..., v1.x-dev, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 3.0.0, 3.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
```

Comment: Its in the message,  abraham/twitteroauth 1.2.0 requires php ^7.2 || ^7.3 || ^7.4 -> your php version (8.0.9) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/abraham/twitteroauth clearly supports PHP8

Comment: You need to pull in a more recent version of twitteroauth in order to have PHP 8 Support. 1.2.0 is as stated in error message made for up to PHP 7.4. Version 2.0.0 of said plugin supports PHP ^8.0

Comment: But...that's what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to update it...

Comment: Trying to force 2.0.0 or anything other version gives errors:

Comment: Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires abraham/twitteroauth ^1.2, 2.0.0, found abraham/twitteroauth[dev-dependabot/npm_and_yarn/concurrently-6.2.1, dev-dependabot/npm_and_yarn/path-parse-1.0.7, dev-dependabot/npm_and_yarn/prettier/plugin-php-0.17.3, dev-dependabot/composer/phpmd/phpmd-2.10.2, dev-dependabot/composer/phpunit/phpunit-9.5.8, dev-main, dev-master, dev-subdomains, 0.2.1, ..., 0.9.2, 1.0.0, ..., v1.x-dev, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 3.0.0, 3.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.

Comment: I find the error to be pretty clear. The packages you are trying to use don't support PHP 8 so the solution is find packages (or upgrade to versions of these packages) that do

Comment: @NaughtySquid The error clearly states thats its NOT supporting PHP8

Comment: So are you saying the twitteroauth is wrong to say it supports PHP8?

Comment: @NaughtySquid version 1.2 that you are trying to use **does not support PHP 8** it's clearly stated at https://packagist.org/packages/abraham/twitteroauth#1.2.0

Comment: I'm not trying to use 1.2. I literally said in a comment above trying to force a newer version, which is the entire point of the post, gives errors shown.

Comment: **Root composer.json requires abraham/twitteroauth ^1.2** that is not trying to force a new anything.

Comment: Am I supposed to edit the json manually to a new version? I thought the entire point of the upgrade system, especially when I tell it a version number, is to actually do the upgrade?

Comment: `composer update` will not automatically update your `composer.json` it will only update `composer.lock`. It will refuse to force a version that does not conform to your `composer.json` to prevent you from accidentally installing a major revision that will likely break your code. You need to use `composer require  abraham/twitteroauth:^2.0` or manually edit your `composer.json` to actually change the file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: update to the versions wanted in composer.json.

Comment: This had negative votes, but may actually be a correct answer. Whoever have this problem, try updating `php` version in your composer file (under the `config`), removing the vendor folder and .lock file, and then running a `composer install` to get the new dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```